# Cant use fragments on Thymeleaf in Spring 4 + MVC

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

It's good to say that I am learning Spring MVC and recently I am trying to create a template I can re-use for my views. To implement Thymeleaf 3.0.9 in my Spring 4.2.0 application I used this guide: https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/thymeleaf-views.html

After doing what the guide says I am able to send attributes and show it in the view, but at the time of using `fragments` it just won't parse any `th attribute` on html tag.

Here are the dependencies I am calling from **pom.xml**

```
    <!-- Thymeleaf -->
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
       <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
       <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
       <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
       <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Here is where I configure the resolver **MyWebConfig.java**

```
        @EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class MyWebConfig {

  @Autowired
  ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  @Bean
  public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine(){
      SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
      templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
      return templateEngine;
  }

  @Bean
  public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver(){
      SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
      templateResolver.setApplicationContext(this.applicationContext);
      templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/template/");
      templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
      templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
      return templateResolver;
  }

  @Bean
  public ViewResolver viewResolver(){
      ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
      viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
      return viewResolver;
  }
}
```

Here is my views **directory structure**:

[image: Directory Structure]

Here is my layout.html (there are many tests, none working)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"  xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
<head th:include="template/header.html::header"></head>
<body>

 <h3>Hello<span th:text="${message}"></span></h3>
  <p th:insert="/template/footer.html::footer"></p>
 <p th:insert="base::footer"></p>
 <p th:include="/template/footer.html::footer"></p>
 <p th:include="base::footer"></p>
  <p th:replace="/template/footer.html::footer"></p>
 <p th:replace="base::footer"></p>

</html>
```

Here is my **footer.html**

```
<p th:fragment="footer">This is the footer</p>
```

Here is my **header.html**

```
<head th:fragment="header">
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Header</title>
</head>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/template/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.andrex" />



</beans>
```

And here is the result:

[image]

Can somebody please guide me?

Comment: Did you try my updated answer ?

Comment: Yes I did. Do you have another idea?

Comment: Did my answer work ?

Comment: I replayed at your answer. I did what you asked and now it is showing me the view but still not rendering. Here is an image: ibb.co/dVar0K

Comment: Check my updated answer and git project. Let us know about your result.

Comment: Please try changing `<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"  xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">` this section with `<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">` in your project. Not in my project.

Comment: I did try this and same issue.